# Проверка истинности выражения

Tags: c++, перегрузка-операторов

С клавиатуры через пробел вводится:
строка str1, 
знак операции < > == >= <= != , 
строка str2.

Проверьте истинность неравенства/равенства.

Написал код, но не знаю как довести до ума. Если кто-нибудь знает, помогите))
Спасибо!

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <cstring>
    #include <string>
    using namespace std;

    class String{
        size_t len;
        char *str;
    public:
        String (): len(0), str(nullptr){}
        String(const String&src);
        String(const char *str);
        ~String() { delete[] str; }
        size_t length() const { return len; }
        bool operator <(const String&s);
        bool operator >(const String&s);
        bool operator ==(const String&s);
        bool operator <=(const String&s);
        bool operator >=(const String&s);
        bool operator !=(const String&s);
        friend istream &operator >>(istream &in, String &s);
        friend ostream &operator <<(ostream &out, const String s);
    };

    String::String(const String &src){
        len = src.len;
        this->str = new char[len+1];
        strncpy(str, src.str, len);
    }

    String::String(const char*s){
        len = strlen(s);
        str = new char[len+1];
        strncpy(str, s, len);
    }

    bool String::operator ==(const String &s){
        return strncmp(str, s.str, len)== 0;
    }
    bool String::operator <=(const String &s){
        return *this == s.str || *this < s.str;
    }
    bool String::operator >=(const String &s){
        return *this == s.str || *this > s.str;
    }

    bool String::operator !=(const String &s){
        return !strncmp(str, s.str, len);
    }
    bool String::operator <(const String &s){
        return strncmp(str, s.str, len) < 0;
    }
    bool String::operator >(const String &s){
        return strncmp(str, s.str, len) > 0;
    }    

    istream &operator >>(istream &in, String &s){
        char *buf = new char[100001];
        in.getline(buf, 100000);
        delete [] s.str;
        s.len = strlen(buf);
        s.str = new char[s.len+1];
        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < s.len; ++i)
            s.str[i] = buf[i];
        delete [] buf;
        return in;
    }

    ostream &operator <<(ostream &out, String s){
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < s.len; ++i)
            out << s.str[i];
        return out;
    }


    int main(){
    String a, b;
    char s;
    cin >> a >> s >> b;

    if(s == ">")
    cout << (a > b? "YES": "NO");
else if(s == ">=")
    cout << (a >= b? "YES": "NO");
else if(s == "<")
    cout << (a < b? "YES": "NO");
else if(s == "<=")
    cout << (a <= b? "YES": "NO");
else if(s == "==")
    cout <<(a == b? "YES": "NO");
else if(s == "!=")
    cout <<(a != b? "YES": "NO");

    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: первый раз вижу такое выражение `if(cin >> a >> b >> c;)` и вроде на сколько я знаю, оно всегда будет являться `true`

Comment: Да, true, но я не знал как и поэтому, так написал, т.к. не знаю как реализовать.

Comment: посмотрите что такое "польская нотация". это подходящий алгоритм, для вашего случая.

Comment: @Insider, если точку с запятой убрать, то будет вполне нормальное выражение. И нет, оно не всегда true, а только если все значения удалось успешно прочитать.

Comment: Вводятся строки или числа?

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, вы хотите следующие.
Человек вводит первое число, вводит оператор (больше, меньше и тд) и второе число.
Вы хотите отловить эти числа и оператор и вывести на экран информацию а-ля, 10 больше 9.. 10 равен 10 и тд... Такое реализуемо как пример таким методом. Написал на скорую руку, думаю код сам за себя говорит.

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
  std::string str1;
  std::string str2;
  std::string str3;

  getline (std::cin, str1);
  getline (std::cin, str2);
  getline (std::cin, str3);

  if(str2.compare("==") == 0)
  {
      if(str1.compare(str3) == 0)
      {
          std::cout << "True";
      }else{
          std::cout << "False";
      }
  }else{
      std::cout << "Wrong Compare";
  }

}
```

Comment: Я функцию compare не знаю, попробую разобраться. Это что-то вроде strcmp?  Но смысл задания Вы поняли правильно. Это задание у нас в теме перегрузка операторов в классе.

Comment: @Trulimon да, тоже самое и работает также. Обновил немного код (забыл нолик)

Comment: Да, видимо, это правильно, но только для одно случая, а там 6 знаков и ещё два варианта ответа на каждый знак, придётся 12 сравнений писать. Надо бы как то привязать к перегрузке оператора.

Comment: @Trulimon 12 сравнений не нужно писать. Мой код, это как пример для того, чтобы указать что не правильно. В вашем случае это int main(). Все что нужно есть и вам осталось дописать, функцию, которая будет принимать числа и сам оператор (от перегрузки), после уже выводить true или false

Comment: Вот смотрите, внёс изменения функцию main,согласно смыслу Вашей идеи, но по своему, . Но пока не компилируется ищу ошибку. Подскажите, если видите ошибку. Следующим этапом перенесу  в функцию операций сравнений.

Comment: @Trulimon первые ошибки которые я вижу: добавьте `#include <string>` и вместо `const char arr[5]` - `const char arr[6]`. Вы работаете с `char`´ом, ему нужен всегда дополнительный байт в конце.

Comment: Добавил, Qt выдаёт ошибку: "main.cpp:82: ошибка: narrowing conversion of '15933' from 'int' to 'char' inside { } [-Wnarrowing]
     const char arr[] = {'>', '>=', '<', '<=', '==', '!='};"

Comment: В версии с массивом выдавало ошибку из-за того что были сдвоенные символы типа "<=", если оставить только одинарные, то ошибка исчезала. Поэтому я убрал массив и сравнил напрямую внутри условного оператора. Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: @Insider А зачем использовать `str2.compare("==") == 0` вместо `str2 == "=="`?